# Python: subclassing tuples and operators

Tags: python, oop, operators, tuples, subclass

I am subclassing tuple. I want to override the equal method. It doesn't seem to be working. This is my minimum working example:

```
class OPS(tuple): 
    def __new__(self, data):
        self=tuple(data)
        return self

    def __eq__(A,B):
        print 'Hi'
        return True

O1=OPS([1,2,3])
O2=OPS([1,2,4])
O1==O2
```

It returns `False`, when it should be printing `'Hi'` and then returning `True`. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong? I bet it is quite stupid, but I am at loss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is in your `__new__` method is creating your objects. You're returning regular `tuple` instances, not instances of your subclass, so the `__eq__` method you've written will never be called.

Try changing `__new__` to:

```
def __new__(cls, data):
    self = super(OPS, cls).__new__(cls, data)
    return self
```

The `self` value returned by this version will be an `OPS` instance.

Answer (score 5):

You are returning a `tuple` instance in `__new__`, not an instance of `OPS`. You can however skip overriding `__new__` in this case since you're not altering the input parameters (in which case `__new__` would be needed since `tuple` is an immutable type). This works as expected, for example:

```js
class OPS(tuple):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True

o1 = OPS([1,2,3])
o2 = OPS([1,2,4])

print o1 == o2
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually do need to work with the input parameters for my particular problem but I thought writing a minimum working example would make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your overwritten the == in OPS class, while O1 and O2 have tuple class.